# Google Calendar Sync and Outlook - Can I make it sync to a calendar other than the default General calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

I am trying to sync my work email to my Google Calendar.  I downloaded and setup Google Calendar Sync.  It works, however all events from my work calendar on outlook syncs to my default General Calendar.  I have a Google Calendar called Work that is not the default calendar.  Is it possible to have it sync only to that calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new Google Calendar account which would only be used for syncing your work account. Then you could share out your work calendar to your personal calendar for viewing online, and import them both in to Outlook for local viewing.

I haven't tried this, and I don't know exactly how you have everything set up, but could be worth a go.

Comment: I like this idea.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Google Calender Sync with my outlook works to my new work gmail account.  Shared this account to my main gmail account, named it Work.  Google Sync for my iPhone works with my shared calendar perfectly.  Hassle free sync.

Answer (score 3):

Google Calendar Sync [only syncs with your primary calendar](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=98565).

I've been using a program for years called [SyncMyCal](http://www.syncmycal.com/home.htm) that will do what you need. The free version only supports manual syncing, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some other free WebDAV based syncing service like [Synqya](http://synqya.appspot.com)  that allows you to sync your Outlook events with any of your Google Calendars

Answer (score 1):

**[Calendar Sync +](http://calendarsyncplus.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1433829)**
This app could be your solution, worls well with all outlook configurations (tested in corporate and general configurations)

Select outlook calendar from different profiles and mailboxes

- Synchronize calendar entries from selected Outlook calendar to
  selected Google calendar
- Calendar Entry Info includes description,    Location, reminder and
  attendees
- Date Range Selection for Sync
- Deletes duplicate entries
- Add/Delete calendar entries to Google thru batch request(faster performance (fewer web requests))
- Check for latest releases of the software
- Setup Sync Frequency

  - Hourly
  - Daily
  - Weekly

PS : I am the co-author/contributor to the application